# Chrome - flexbox - containing box

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

Please see this pen in Chrome: [codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGNvKj)

html:

```
<div class='flexbox'>
  <div class='static'>ddd
  </div>
  <div class='flex'>
    <div class='flex-child'>
      <div class='container'>
        *** very long text here *** ...</div>
    </div>
    <div class='flex-child'>hhh
    </div>
    <div class='flex-child'>hhh
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='static'>ddd
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
html,body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.flexbox{
  position:absolute;
  background:black;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.flex{
  background:blue;
  flex:1;
  display:flex;
  position : relative;
}

.flex-child{
  background:red;
  width:100%;
  display:block;
  color:white;
  position : relative;
}

.static{
  background:transparent;
  width:100%;
  color:yellow;
}

.container{
  position : relative;
  background:magenta;
  height:100%;      
}
```

I believe the example is almost selfexplanatory.
The question is: How to do it, to have the .container div ready to host any kind of content, unknown at the moment, and not to overlap over the footer.

try to remove background colors. the text from .container is visually mixed with the text of the .static footer. How to arrange it and have the .content div and its text not to overlap the footer?

edit:

The footer should be at the bottom of the viewport.
No explicit sizes or dimensions are allowed to be set in css.

Please take my question as an example, an experiment.
My concern is not to use any explicit sizes or dimensions e.g. header height 50px, I want to have the layout as general as possible. so if I formulated my question in other words:
pls in my original codepen delete all the text from the .container and then check the .container height via developer tools.  It will be 0, but I would expect it to be the same height as it's parent .flex-child is.
I know that it probably would not be following the specification, but how to achieve this?

edit 2:
I described my problem in more detail in another question, with codepen and picture. Thank you for your ideas. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32114925/header-flexible-body-with-nested-flexible-columns-footer-concrete-layout

thank you

Comment: Why are you using `position:absolute` on the container? It's really not clear to me what you are trying to do.

Comment: Trying to combine flexbox and absolute positioning makes very, very little sense IMHO.

Comment: the absolute positioning was a relict from the codepen I forked to create this one. Actually I wanted to comment on another question here on stackoverflow, but I found out I can not comment because I am a new-commer and have unsufficient reputation.
Anyway, thanks for comments

Answer (score 0):

Your actual requirements are a little unclear as to the actual position of the `footer`.

**Option 1.**

The `footer` should be at the bottom of the viewport and so the whole page must be contained within the viewport.

In this case the content of the `main` element can be any size and a scrollbar is added when content will overflow the height of the element.

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/GJaVQp)

**Option 2.**

The `footer` should be at the bottom of the *page/document* and the page can be any height (presumably with a minimum of the viewport height).

In this case the content of the `main` element can be any size and the page/dicument will increase in size to accomodate it

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/aOreKP)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and examples. Yes, the option 1 is the case.

Comment: Thnks for the answer and examples. Yes the option 1 is the case.
Please take my question as an example, an experiment.
My concern is not to use any explicit sizes or dimensions e.g. header height 50px, I want to have the layout as general as possible. so if I formulated my question in other words:
pls in my original pen delete all the text from the .container and then check the .container height via developer tools.  It will be 0, but I would expect it to be the same height as it's parent .flex-child is.
I know that it probably would not following the specification, but how to achieve this? TY

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. You can change wll thouse values in the `flex` statements to `auto` or play with to suit your requirements- http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/xGoKXG

Comment: I am asking exactly what I wrote, how to achieve the .container would be even empty exactly 100% height of it's parent. 
In other words, I would expect the flexbox to create containing boxes on flex-items for its childs. 
100% height is a common problem, I thought flexbox approach could/should solve it, and now I try to get the knowledge.
Thanks for answers.